# Is there a way to add Div Block, Headers and other elements Django/Python's static folder?

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to add Div Block, Headers and other elements Django/Python's static folder?

I thought this would be simple, just use the same general formatting as I did with the stylesheet from the Django tutorial but I couldn't get it to work.  Not sure if I'm on the right path of the most optimal way to set it up.

`<title>"{% static 'polls/blah.txt' %}" /> </title>`

Basically I am trying to make it so that all of my html pages can be altered by changing only one file rather than going into each page and changing the title or other text that might appear on each page.

Comment: There seems to be something missing in your question.

Comment: Why is it that the file extension of your stylesheet is ".txt"?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just changed it to text thinking it would make a difference was more of a visual example of what I am trying to accomplish rather than the exact code.  Basically I am trying to make it so that all of my html pages can be altered by changing only one file rather than going into each page and changing the title or other text that might appear on each page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "Template Inheritance" and is covered very thoroughly [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#id1).

To achieve this, you can either set up a base template with [blocks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#block) that can be overridden in child templates that [extend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-extends) the base. Or you can create template "partials" and [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#include) them in your other templates.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you, I just didn't know what terminology to look for in the docs.